# Why Am I Getting This Bracket Error In My Code?

Tags: c

So, i'm having a bracket issue in line 83:9 or where the slashes are. it's telling me " error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token", I don't understand how i am receiving this error. If somebody can explain to me how I'm receiving it, thank you.

not much

```
_Bool palindromes(char string[])
    {
    int i = 0;
    while(string[i]=0 != '\0')
            {
            i++;
            int last_place = i - 1;
                    for(int n=0; n<=last_place; n++)
                    {
                    if(string[n] == string[last_place])
                    {
                    last_place--;
                    continue;
                    }

                    if(n !=last_place)
                    {
                    return false;
                    }

                    }
            }
    }


    { //here is the bracket it's detecting
    int i = 0;
    while(string[i]=0 != '\0')
            {
            i++;
            int last_place = i - 1;
                    for(int n=0; n<=last_place; n++)
                    {
                    if(string[n] == string[last_place])
                    {
                    return true;
                    }
                    }


             }
    }
```

Comment: The close bracket ie. `}` before your issue closes the `palindromes` function, so unless this entire block is inside another structure, then this will be your issue

Answer (score 1):

If you fix the identation you have

```
_Bool palindromes(char string[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while(string[i]=0 != '\0')
    {
        i++;
        int last_place = i - 1;
        for(int n=0; n<=last_place; n++)
        {
            if(string[n] == string[last_place])
            {
                last_place--;
                continue;
            }
            if(n !=last_place)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}   <---------- ups, function ends here


{ //here is the bracket it's detecting
    int i = 0;
    while(string[i]=0 != '\0')
```

This clearly show that you have one `}` too much